# Difficulties in setting website language using Playwright

Tags: c#, playwright

I am trying to write a test in Playwright to verify if the language displayed on the website matches the language set in the browser settings. The website always selects the first language from the settings-language array in Chrome, and there is no header indicating the current language.

I tried using the following code to get all the languages set in the browser:
`var language = await page.EvaluateAsync<string[]>("() => navigator.languages");`
However, this only returns "de-DE" and not the entire array of languages set in the settings-language (only the first language in the array).

I am unable to permanetly set the language of the Playwright browser to English, and even when I managed to change the language using `navigator.language`, the language reverted back to German after refreshing the page, and the content of the site did not change to "en-US" even momentarily. Even changing the location to "en-US" or geolocation to the USA did not work.

I have manually verified that changing the language settings in the browser does affect the language displayed on the website. Therefore, the crux of the issue lies in finding a way to permantly change the language of the Playwright browser.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Playwright;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace BlazorServerTest.dplaywright.test;

public class LanguageTest
{
    // checks the language of the browser + test, if the language is the same as the text shown  
    [Fact]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        // Playwright 
        using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
        // Browser
        await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
        {
            Headless = false,
        });
        var context = await browser.NewContextAsync(new BrowserNewContextOptions
        {
            Permissions = new[] { "geolocation" },
            Locale = "en-US",
            ExtraHTTPHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["Accept-Language"] = "en-US,en;q=0.9"
            },
            Geolocation = new Geolocation
            {
                Longitude = -95.712891f,
                Latitude = 37.09024f,
                Accuracy = 100,
            },
        });
        // Page
        var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
        await page.GotoAsync(url: "https://localhost/");

        // Test Code      
        var language = await page.EvaluateAsync<string>("() => navigator.language"); 

        // this actually works, but if you refresh the page then the language is resorted to german again + the displayed language does not change (so variable "language2" is "en-US", but the language doesn't get updated)
        await page.EvaluateAsync($@"
        () => {{
        var newLang = {{language: 'en-US'}};
        
        Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'language', {{ value: newLang.language, configurable: true }});
        Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'languages', {{ get: () => [newLang.language], configurable: true }});
        }}
        ");

        var language2 = await page.EvaluateAsync<string>("() => navigator.language");

        // after reload the language3 is back to german
        await page.ReloadAsync();

        var language3 = await page.EvaluateAsync<string>("() => navigator.language");

        // here I want to check, if the text is german or english - if the page is getting displayed in english, then the variable isExistEng is true otherwise false
        var isExistGer = await page.Locator("text='Übersicht fehlerhafte VPD-Druckaufträge'").IsVisibleAsync();

        var isExistEng = await page.Locator("text='Failed VPD print jobs overview'").IsVisibleAsync();
```

Things I already tried, which don't work:

```
    await page.EvaluateAsync("document.documentElement.setAttribute('lang', 'en-US')");

    await page.SetExtraHTTPHeadersAsync(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Accept-Language", "en-US" }
    });

    await page.EvaluateAsync(@$"() => {{
        const html = document.documentElement;
        html.lang = 'en';
        html.setAttribute('lang', 'en-US');
    }}");

    var client = new HttpClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost/");
    request.Headers.Remove("Accept-Language");
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "de");
    
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    Console.WriteLine("response: " + response.StatusCode);
    
    var request1 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost/");
    request1.Headers.Remove("Accept-Language");
    request1.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en");
    
    var response1 = await client.SendAsync(request1);
    Console.WriteLine("response2: " + response1.StatusCode);
```

Comment: Is this [github issue #739](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/739) related?   Pavel recommends to use `browser.newContext({locale: 'en-US'})` but others gave a thumbs down so this might not work.

Answer (score 0):

As-of Playwright 1.41.1 this is working for me very well (it probably doesn't matter that I use Python instead of C#)

```py
    context.browser_context = context.browser.new_context(record_video_dir=VIDEO_DIR, locale='en-US')
```

https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-browser#browser-new-context-option-locale

> locale str (optional)
>
> Specify user locale, for example en-GB, de-DE, etc. Locale will affect navigator.language value, Accept-Language request header value as well as number and date formatting rules. Defaults to the system default locale. Learn more about emulation in our emulation guide.

The documentation for .NET says the same thing:
https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-browser#browser-new-context-option-locale